# Is maven release plugin following conventional commit format?

Tags: maven, versioning, maven-release-plugin, semantic-versioning

I am planning to configure semantic versioning for maven project and for CI. Is maven release plugin following conventional commit format? So it will increase the major.minor.patch as per commit message and update changelog.md. Something similar to semantic-release concept in npm. I wonder if there is anything similar in Maven?

Answer (score 1):

This your solution: **smartling cc4j conventional commits**

#### Usage

This plugin works together with the [Maven Release Plugin] to create
conventional commit compliant releases for your Maven projects

Install the Plugin

In your main `pom.xml` file add the plugin:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.smartling.cc4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>conventional-commits-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${version}</version>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Release a Version

```
mvn conventional-commits:version release:prepare
mvn release:perform
```

[Source](https://github.com/foo4u/conventional-commits-for-java)

Answer (score 1):

With the maven-release-plugin version 3.0.0 it is now possible to do conventional commits as a part of the release process.

This is done by adding a new VersionPolicy that does this calculation.

I wrote this one https://github.com/nielsbasjes/conventional-commits-maven-release

In its simplest form you can now do something like this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>nl.basjes.maven.release</groupId>
      <artifactId>conventional-commits-version-policy</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <configuration>
    <projectVersionPolicyId>ConventionalCommitsVersionPolicy</projectVersionPolicyId>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```